# Wordpress Ignores new Site Url and Home when hosted on another domain

Tags: php, wordpress, aws-amplify

I have the following set up for a client:

Wordpress hosted at siteground.com with `externalhost.com/blog` => working Wordpress Installation.

AWS App "myapp.com" managed by Amplify with a rewrite for /blog which should lead to `externalhost.com/blog` but show the user `myapp.com/blog`.

I then switched the siteurl and home in the `wp-config.php` file:

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://myapp.com/blog' );
define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://myapp.com/blog' );
```

It pretty much works, but there are some cases which aren't working. So far I have noticed:
Pagination in the pages section keeps the links for the next page with `externalhost.com/blog`.
Menu Section links redirect to the `externalhost.com/blog` part.

It feels that not everywhere in the Wordpress the link has changed above all in the pagination I wasn't able to find a solution. Maybe someone has experienced the same behaviour or ideas where I can modify those behaviours?

Answer (score 0):

When switching the site url or moving the site to new hosting etc I have found i need to do a search & replace in the DB which can be done with a plugin like: https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/ search for the old url `externalhost.com` & replace with the new url `myapp.com` this should resolve your issue, the plugin usually allows you to do a dry run before making the changes.

Also a another way to do a migration is also use a plugin like: https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/

Once your done with the plugins you should be able to remove them from your project

Comment: Exactly. Making all the changes necessary to migrate a site from one URL to another is gnarly detail-oriented work if you stick-build it command by command. Use a migration plugin; their authors have debugged many if not most of the weird edge cases you have to consider.

Comment: Sorry didn't mentioned it, but I already did it. The problem I believe is its host-server and url-address are different. And that probably the pagination for example uses a dynamic variable which asks for the host-server and not for the site_url or home variables

Comment: In the pagination for example it creates the link like to following: 
  $current_url = set_url_scheme( 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );

But this takes externalhost.com as link and not the myapp.com url. Tough if I do in the console window.location.host it return myapp.com

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, doing the following in the wp-config.php

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = str_replace ('externalhost.com', 'myapp.com', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

Now it works.

Reference: [Change value of $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] on Bitnami Wordpress behind Azure CDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65534818/change-value-of-serverhttp-host-on-bitnami-wordpress-behind-azure-cdn)